# how to use angular-gantt(angularjs library) in angular 10 or angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-gantt

[here is the image of the code and i don't know how to use it in angular 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtCEN.png)hello there i'm new to angular, i want angular-gantt [angular-gantt](https://www.angular-gantt.com/get-started/) in my angular 10 project can somebody explain me step by step procedure for doing this... event i tried adding js and css in angular.json file.

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/themes/default.theme.css",
          "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.css",
          "node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
          "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css",
          "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
          "src/scss/style.scss",
          "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-lite.min.css",
          "node_modules/angular-gantt/dist/angular-gantt.min.css"

        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
          "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js",
          "node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote-lite.min.js",
          "node_modules/angular-gantt/dist/angular-gantt.min.js"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps below,

1. Import the GanttModule in app.module.ts file from the ej2-angular-gantt package.
   import { GanttModule } from 'your downloaded location';
2. Import and inject GanttModule within providers section of app.module.ts.
   @NgModule({
   declarations: [
   ..
   ],
   imports: [
   ..
   GanttModule,
   ..
   ],
   })
3. Refer the CSS file for Angular Gantt in styles.css
4. Example :
   Configure data and taskfield in your ts and bind it in html as follows,

   <ejs-gantt id="GanttSample"
   [dataSource]="data"
   height= "500px"
   width="800px"
   [taskFields]= "taskfield">

Comment: actually i want too use angular-gantt which is a angularjs lib not this... coz this is a paid lib

Comment: You can install using npm or yarn which is free. All other steps are same. Command is npm add angular-gantt --save

Comment: You can check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-gantt

Comment: i want to use this... https://www.angular-gantt.com/get-started/  
and the when i installed it using "npm install angular-gantt --save" it isntalled in node modules but when i tried to import the module in app.module.ts with "import { GanttModule } from 'angular-gantt' " it is saying 

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/angular-gantt/dist/angular-gantt.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ElementQueries' in '/home/mohit/Desktop/athmin projects/pronnelfrontend/node_modules/angular-gantt/dist'